# Ruby Find by column and row in a multidimensional array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

So here is what my array looks like

```
[["Date", "Patient 1", "Patient 2", "Patient 3"],
["8/1/2014",0,0,0]
["8/2/2014",0,0,0]
["8/3/2014",0,0,0]]
```

I need to be able to find the index for "Patient 2" - "8/2/2014" which would of course be array[2][2] so that I can then change it's value from 0 to something else. How do I find that using the column and row names I've layed out?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find the row, you can use `find` and compare the value to the first element in each row:

```
matrix.find { |x| x[0] == "8/2/2014" }
# => ["8/2/2014", 0, 0, 0]
```

To find the column index, you can use `index` on the first array:

```
matrix[0].index("Patient 2")
# => 2
```

You can wrap it in a method:

```
def change_matrix(matrix, row, col, new_val)
  matrix.find { |x| x[0] == row }[matrix[0].index(col)] = new_val
end

change_matrix(matrix, '8/2/2014', 'Patient 2', 5)

matrix
# => [["Date", "Patient 1", "Patient 2", "Patient 3"], 
#     ["8/1/2014", 0, 0, 0], 
#     ["8/2/2014", 0, 5, 0], 
#     ["8/3/2014", 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
a = [["Date", "Patient 1", "Patient 2", "Patient 3"],["8/1/2014",0,0,0],["8/2/2014",0,0,0],["8/3/2014",0,0,0]]
b = a.transpose

print a[0][1] + " " + b[0][1]
```

Demo: http://runnable.com/U-oULwIJWFYZpeOx/transpose-for-ruby

Comment: You should not assume that `"Patient 1"` is in any particular column or that the given date i is in a specific row. The patient id and date should both be variables.